# Find the matrix $P$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A= \begin{bmatrix}1 & -2 & 3\\-2 & 6 &-9 \\3 & -9 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$

Find $P$ with non-negative integer entries and has determinant $2$.

$P^TAP=\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 & 0\\0 & b &0 \\0 & 0 & -38 \end{bmatrix} a<b$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: This problem is posted on behalf on my sister. But I guess Eigenvalue decomposition can be used, but I am not sure.

Comment: Have you found the eigenvalues?

Comment: @John the eigenvalues of this matrix are not of a simple form.

Comment: @Ale : You are right. The hint is a bit misleading. Should be doing some row reduction instead.